# Some question on $F(z) := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \text{log} \Big(1+\frac{z}{n} \Big)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need some help to solve this exercise:

Show that the function $$F(z) := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \text{log} \Big(1+\frac{z}{n} \Big)$$ is well defined and holomorphic in $D_1(0) := \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 1 \}$

Show that it is possible to extend $F$ to an holomorphic funcion in $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty,-1]$

---

I'll give my answer but I'm not sure it is a good way to proceed. My apologies for every bad error I did.

Let's consider $F(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(z) \ $. If I consider the determination of the logarithm where $\text{log} \Big(1+\frac{z}{n} \Big)$ evaluated in $z=0$ is $0$ then $f_n$ are all well defined in $D_1(0)$ and they are also holomorphic.

At this point I consider $D_R(0)$ with $0<R<1$. In this region we definitively have $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big | \frac{1}{n} \text{log} \Big(1+\frac{z}{n} \Big) \Big | \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big | \frac{1}{n} \text{log} \Big(1+\frac{R}{n} \Big) \Big |$$

For $R$ fixed and for $n$ enough large $\text{log} \Big(1+\frac{R}{n} \Big) \sim \frac{R}{n}$, so the tail of the last sum is

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{R}{n^2} $$ which is convergent for every $R$. At this point using Weierstrass' Theorem we can conclude that $f_n$ is convergent on every $D_R(0)$ so $F$ is holomorphic.

---

For the second part I thought like this: operating the cut $(-\infty,-1]$ in the complex plane and reasoning as we did before, we still have $f_n$ holomorphic in $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty,-1]$

At this point, once fixed $z$ in such domain, we can expand the log to his power series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \text{log} \Big(1+\frac{z}{n} \Big) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \Big( \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1} \frac{1}{n^{k}} \frac{z^k}{k} \Big) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1} \frac{1}{n^{k+1}} \frac{z^k}{k}$$

Changing the sums and isolating $n$:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \Big( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{k+1}} \Big) (-1)^{k+1} \frac{z^k}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} C_k (-1)^{k+1} \frac{z^k}{k}$$

Now, what can I conclude? Can I use Liebniz's theorem? Please let me know if I am wrong and how to solve this exercize correctly.

Comment: You should justify the interchange of sums and show that the resulting series converges on $D_1(0)$.

Comment: Why can't I change the sums "freely"? About the convergence in $D_1(0)$ you can minorize z with R as made before and $(-1)^{k+1} R^k/k$ converges absolutely because of the choice $R<1$. But what outside $D_1(0)$ ?

Comment: "Why can't I change the sums freely?" - wrong question. The correct question is "why *can* I change the sums freely?". Until you have an answer to that question, you cannot interchange the order of summation (or any pair of limits).